# Vue.js duplicate a component twice in the screen : How to avoid this problem?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I created Vue app in VS code. When I try to run the app, the home component is rendered twice in the screen.

Here is the resulted homepage screen screenshot:

[image]

Here is the Home.vue code:
[image]

Comment: Code is preferred to images as it can be [searched for and tested out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12892553) and in addition [Users from certain countries can't view hosted images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407369/12892553)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Home component must be referenced twice. For example in App.vue or some other component you’re using.